# ListItem Schema [schema.org/ItemList] error: "All values provided for url must have the same domain."

Tags: schema.org, google-schemas

I am facing issue with this ListItem schema validation on https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/
Getting error

> All values provided for url must have the same domain.

I have provided same domain in every URL field.

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "ItemList",
    "name": "Tech News",
    "url": "http://m.gadgetsnow.com/tech-news",
    "itemListElement": [
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": "1",
            "url": "http://m.gadgetsnow.com/tech-news/are-tvs-going-out-of-fashion/articleshow/58375579.cms",
            "name": "Are TVs going out of fashion?",
            "image": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "contentUrl": "http://m.gadgetsnow.com/photo/58375579.cms",
                "width": "360",
                "height": "270",
                "url": "http://m.gadgetsnow.com/photo/58375579.cms"
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": "2",
            "url": "http://m.gadgetsnow.com/tech-news/reliance-jio-discounts-are-not-going-anywhere-for-now-heres-why/articleshow/58374335.cms",
            "name": "Reliance Jio discounts are not going anywhere for now, here's why",
            "image": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "contentUrl": "http://m.gadgetsnow.com/photo/58374335.cms",
                "width": "360",
                "height": "270",
                "url": "http://m.gadgetsnow.com/photo/58374335.cms"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: [Likely the same bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40400319/1591669).

Answer (score 1):

You may try using the correct version of `ItemList`. There are `Separately` and `Combined` marked up `ItemLists` as referred [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings#how-to-mark-up-host-specific-lists).

> - If your items are on the same page, please use the version with items inside, the Combined one.
> - Otherwise, if you point to different pages inside and your items are not on one page, please DON’T put item element with type and other
>     description inside, the Separately marked up one.

Additional references:

- [Error in Google SDTT: "All values provided for url must point to the same page."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40180660/error-in-google-sdtt-all-values-provided-for-url-must-point-to-the-same-page)
- [Schema.org and ContactPoint use with validation failure: “All values provided for http://www.example.com/ must have the same domain.”](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101133/schema-org-and-contactpoint-use-with-validation-failure-all-values-provided-fo)

Comment: There's an error in validator. Markup [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings#how-to-mark-up-host-specific-lists) are also throwing error on SDTT

Answer (score 0):

There are no bugs. Be careful if the [validator](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) gives errors, a big chance that rich snippets will not work.

So what's the problem? The first thing to note is that in the ListItem object, either [url](https://schema.org/url) or [item](https://schema.org/item) can be used. As the [schema.org](https://schema.org/) documentation says, `item` is used for:

> an artist’s list of data artists (e.g. an 'artist' in a list of 'artists')

And the most important thing that I noticed: if you use `item` and you want the scheme to be correct, then the domain and its parts should be the same in all ListItem, but the anchors are different, which are separated from the url using the `#` symbol. Google gives a [specific example](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings):

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "itemListElement": [
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": "1",
      "item": {
        "@context": "https://schema.org/",
        "@type": "Recipe",
        "url": "http://example.com/big_list_of_recipes#cherry_pie",
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": "2",
      "item": {
        "@context": "https://schema.org/",
        "@type": "Recipe",
        "url": "http://example.com/big_list_of_recipes#coffee_cake",
        ...
      }
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

As you can see in the list, the same URL is used `http://example.com/big_list_of_recipe`, but different anchors: `#cherry_pie` and `#coffee_cake`.
But still it is not clarity how to specify the URL, which is a separate page for the thing.