# What should be inside URL?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data, microformats

I have a list of organizations on a page.
I have created a `JSON-LD` block for them.
You can find it at the end of the message.
After checking it with the validator, I got an error.
`All values provided for itemListElement.item.url must point to the same page.`

At the moment organization URL point to the company profile.
According to https://schema.org/Organization, it should be `URL of the item.`
Should all organization URLs point to the current page with the list?
But what sense in that?

Also, I want to get a [rating widget](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet#aggregate-rating) in a search at the end.
But google ignoring this list.
What am I doing wrong?
Should I have only one rating per page?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "name": "service pros",
  "itemListOrder": "Unordered",
  "numberOfItems": 3711,
  "itemListElement": [
      {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": 1,
          "item": {
              "@context": "https://schema.org",
              "@type": "Organization",
              "url": "https://example.com/profiel/barotech",
              "name": "Barotech",
              "areaServed": {
                  "@type": "Place",
                  "address": {
                      "@type": "PostalAddress",
                      "addressLocality": "Rotterdam"
                  }
              },
              "aggregateRating": {
                  "@type": "AggregateRating",
                  "ratingValue": 9.6,
                  "reviewCount": 226,
                  "bestRating": 10,
                  "worstRating": 0
              }
          }
      },
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 2,
        "item": {
            "@context": "https://schema.org",
            "@type": "Organization",
            "url": "https://example.com/profiel/felix-montage-service",
            "name": "Felix montage & service",
            "logo": "https://www.example.com/images/sp/thumbnail_small/546ccf07-de13-41bf-9f5c-27f3205ea8f8.jpeg",
            "areaServed": {
                "@type": "Place",
                "address": {
                    "@type": "PostalAddress",
                    "addressLocality": "Den Haag"
                }
            },
            "aggregateRating": {
                "@type": "AggregateRating",
                "ratingValue": 7.9,
                "reviewCount": 28,
                "bestRating": 10,
                "worstRating": 0
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a validator bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40180660/error-in-google-sdtt-all-values-provided-for-url-must-point-to-the-same-page/40329199#40329199. Other tools, like https://extendsclass.com/json-schema-validator.html or https://search.google.com/test/rich-results, don't find any errors in your example

Comment: Look like it is so. But I still don't have any widgets in search querie. So something still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To gain Google rich results mean you have to comply with their guidelines.

You've marked up a list of things which puts you under the carousel guidelines, and you pointed out the error your list has for that:

All values provided for itemListElement.item.url must point to the same page.
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/carousel

If you are marking up full entities within the list they must be for entities that are fully defined on the page, and not on a different page (hence the url restriction). They also have to be one of the limited types they state, which Organization is not. If your list is of entities on other urls then you should just list the url.

But you are wanting review rich snippets.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet

Google does support reviews of Organizations but it is mentioned in an "also" section and I believe has more limited support. Their wording indicates they support reviews but not ratings (stars).

The guidelines on that page also provide extra restrictions for Organization based reviews.

Also, having valid structured data does not guarantee getting rich results. Google has other quality and validity checks they do before awarding a page with the special snippets.

I suspect in your case the issue is that your page is not focusing on reviews for a single thing. And that Organization puts you in the more restrictive category. Aim to get reviews on the pages focused on each organization.

Comment: nice explanation